# error in code that seeks to check for multiple strings in an input text box javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have the following code that is trying to generate a score depending on how many keywords are found in a given text box. It isn't generating any errors, and I cannot see why it isn't working. Update: fixed the typo (which was declaring the last keyword) but it's the logic that is wrong.

When I click the submit button, it will return 1,2,3 IF the keywords are written in order of declaration, but if, for example, I write a sentence with the last keyword, it will return 0, even though the keyword is present.

e.g. if I wrote "that things must be eternal", the score is 0, where as if I wrote "that things must be good", then the score is 1.

I did try to see if 'answer' is being generated when the button is clicked, and it is.

Anyone?

**Here is the javascript code:**

```
<script>
function displayScore(){
    var showscore;
    var answer = document.getElementById('longanswer').value;
    var keyword1 = answer.includes("good");
    var keyword2 = answer.includes("eternal");
    var keyword2 = answer.includes("true");

    if(keyword1==true & keyword2==true & keyword3==true){
            showscore="3";
    } else if(keyword1==true & keyword2==true){
        showscore="2";
    } else if(keyword1==true){
        showscore="1";
    } else {
        showscore="0";
    }

    document.getElementById("displayscore").innerHTML = showscore;
}
</script>
```

**And the whole code in context**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Long Answer Question & Answers</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<form>
<h1> Q and A </h1>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="longanswer">What is the meaning of life?:</label><br>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="100" id="longanswer">
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="displayScore()" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>




<div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-header">Score</div>
  <div class="card-body text-primary">
    <h5 class="card-title">Generating a score for your answer</h5>
    <p class="card-text" id="displayscore">Once you've clicked submit we will display your score for this answer here.</p>
  </div>
</div>




<script>
function displayScore(){
    var showscore;
    var answer = document.getElementById('longanswer').value;
    var keyword1 = answer.includes("good");
    var keyword2 = answer.includes("eternal");
    var keyword2 = answer.includes("true");

    if(keyword1==true & keyword2==true & keyword3==true){
            showscore="3";
    } else if(keyword1==true & keyword2==true){
        showscore="2";
    } else if(keyword1==true){
        showscore="1";
    } else {
        showscore="0";
    }

    document.getElementById("displayscore").innerHTML = showscore;
}
</script>






    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Essentially, I need help with the LOGIC here.

As mentioned I want it to basically score 3 for ANY of the keywords if they are present, 2, if it 'sees' two key words, and 1 for 1.

Possible pseudocode...two alternatives given. Thoughts anyone?

```
<!--
Pseudocode
textbox input id=longanswer
var score
var answer=get the string inside the text input
if answer contains keyword 1, then score=1
f answer contains keyword 1 and keyword 2 then score=2
if answer contains keyword 1 and keyword 2 and keyword 3 then score =3
else 
score=1
display score

//ALTERNATIVE USING FOR LOOP AND ARRAYS
textbox input id=longanswer
var score
var answer=get the string inside the text input
split the string into words, and store the words in an array
for every word in the array
if the word is a match with any keywords in arrayof_keywords
increment score
display score


-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define `keyword3`, instead you accidentally defined `keyword2` twice.

Correct

```
var keyword1 = answer.includes("good");
var keyword2 = answer.includes("eternal");
var keyword2 = answer.includes("true");
```

to

```
var keyword1 = answer.includes("good");
var keyword2 = answer.includes("eternal");
var keyword3 = answer.includes("true");
```

and it works.

### Edit:

You did not match every possible combination of keywords in your code, so e. g. your code didn't handle if "eternal" was the only word that's in the user's answer.

Here's the code for every combination:

```
if (keyword1 == true && keyword2 == true && keyword3 == true) {
  showscore = 3;
} else if (keyword1 == true && keyword2 == true) {
  showscore = 2;
} else if (keyword1 == true && keyword3 == true) {
  showscore = 2; 
} else if (keyword1 == true) {
  showscore = 1;
} else if(keyword2 == true && keyword1 == true) {
  showscore = 2;
} else if (keyword2 == true && keyword3 == true) {
  showscore = 2;
} else if (keyword2 == true) {
  showscore = 1;
} else if (keyword3 == true && keyword1 == true) {
  showscore = 2;
} else if (keyword3 == true && keyword2 == true) {
  showscore = 2;
} else if (keyword3 == true) {
  showscore = 1;
} else {
  showscore = 0;
}
```

And here the whole JS code:

```
function displayScore(){
var showscore;
var answer = document.getElementById('longanswer').value;
var keyword1 = answer.includes("good");
var keyword2 = answer.includes("eternal");
var keyword3 = answer.includes("true");
console.log(keyword1, keyword2, keyword3);

if (keyword1 == true && keyword2 == true && keyword3 == true) {
  showscore = 3;
} else if (keyword1 == true && keyword2 == true) {
  showscore = 2;
} else if (keyword1 == true && keyword3 == true) {
  showscore = 2; 
} else if (keyword1 == true) {
  showscore = 1;
} else if(keyword2 == true && keyword1 == true) {
  showscore = 2;
} else if (keyword2 == true && keyword3 == true) {
  showscore = 2;
} else if (keyword2 == true) {
  showscore = 1;
} else if (keyword3 == true && keyword1 == true) {
  showscore = 2;
} else if (keyword3 == true && keyword2 == true) {
  showscore = 2;
} else if (keyword3 == true) {
  showscore = 1;
} else {
  showscore = 0;
}

document.getElementById("displayscore").innerHTML = showscore;
}
```

Here's the whole code, so you can see the changes in effect:

```js
function displayScore() {
  var showscore;
  var answer = document.getElementById('longanswer').value;
  var keyword1 = answer.includes("good");
  var keyword2 = answer.includes("eternal");
  var keyword3 = answer.includes("true");

  if (keyword1 == true && keyword2 == true && keyword3 == true) {
    showscore = 3;
  } else if (keyword1 == true && keyword2 == true) {
    showscore = 2;
  } else if (keyword1 == true && keyword3 == true) {
    showscore = 2;
  } else if (keyword1 == true) {
    showscore = 1;
  } else if (keyword2 == true && keyword1 == true) {
    showscore = 2;
  } else if (keyword2 == true && keyword3 == true) {
    showscore = 2;
  } else if (keyword2 == true) {
    showscore = 1;
  } else if (keyword3 == true && keyword1 == true) {
    showscore = 2;
  } else if (keyword3 == true && keyword2 == true) {
    showscore = 2;
  } else if (keyword3 == true) {
    showscore = 1;
  } else {
    showscore = 0;
  }

  document.getElementById("displayscore").innerHTML = showscore;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Long Answer Question & Answers</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <h1> Q and A </h1>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="longanswer">What is the meaning of life?:</label><br>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="100" id="longanswer">
    </textarea>
      <br>
      <button onclick="displayScore()" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>




  <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">Score</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary">
      <h5 class="card-title">Generating a score for your answer</h5>
      <p class="card-text" id="displayscore">Once you've clicked submit we will display your score for this answer here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>





  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

### **Second edit:**

If I understood it correctly (according to you pseudo code), I did a second version of the JS code, matching only a few possibilities:

```js
function displayScore() {
  var showscore;
  var answer = document.getElementById('longanswer').value;
  var keyword1 = answer.includes("good");
  var keyword2 = answer.includes("eternal");
  var keyword3 = answer.includes("true");
  
  if (keyword1 == true && keyword2 == false && keyword3 == false) {
    showscore = 1;
  } else if (keyword1 == true && keyword2 == true && keyword3 == false) {
    showscore = 2;
  } else if (keyword1 == true && keyword2 == true && keyword3 == true) {
    showscore = 3;
  } else {
    showscore = 1;
  }

  document.getElementById("displayscore").innerHTML = showscore;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Long Answer Question & Answers</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <h1> Q and A </h1>


    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="longanswer">What is the meaning of life?:</label><br>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="100" id="longanswer">
    </textarea>
      <br>
      <button onclick="displayScore()" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>




  <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">Score</div>
    <div class="card-body text-primary">
      <h5 class="card-title">Generating a score for your answer</h5>
      <p class="card-text" id="displayscore">Once you've clicked submit we will display your score for this answer here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>





  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: actually no, that was a mistake, but there is still an error in the logic of the code ...which is what I am trying to fix.

Comment: for instance, now the button comes up with a score, but it only searches for the keyword in that order. so if the sentence puts the keywords in any other order, a score of 0 is returned, even if the keyword 'good' is entered.

Comment: @MissComputing Edited my answer, now it works as you want it to.

Comment: @MissComputing Updated it again.

Answer (score 0):

CodeF0x is right. you just have to change the variable name and it works. Full code:

```
function displayScore(){
    var showscore;
    var answer = document.getElementById('longanswer').value;
    var keyword1 = answer.includes("good");
    var keyword2 = answer.includes("eternal");
    var keyword3 = answer.includes("true");

    if(keyword1==true & keyword2==true & keyword3==true){
            showscore="3";
    } else if(keyword1==true & keyword2==true){
        showscore="2";
    } else if(keyword1==true){
        showscore="1";
    } else {
        showscore="0";
    }

    document.getElementById("displayscore").innerHTML = showscore;
}
```

**Edit:**
more flexibility with less code:

```
function displayScore(){
    var showscore;
    var answer = document.getElementById('longanswer').value || "";
    var keywords = ["good","eternal","true"];

    showscore = keywords.reduce(function (acc, cur) {
       return acc + answer.contains(cur);
    },0)

    document.getElementById("displayscore").innerHTML = showscore;
}
```

Comment: please see update. bar the syntax/typo error on the variable name, there is a serious logic error. see update in question. Thanks!

Comment: So, I know what is happening - as I imagine you do - if just keyword 1 returns true, then the trigger for showscore1=1 is shown or etc...so it doesn't work as it should. e.g if ANY one of those keywords is written it would be score = 1, if ANY 2, then score = 2, if ANY 3, then score=3. The order should not matter. It is just picking up keywords